# Центрировать элементы по вертикали

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть такой блок:

```html
<div class="container my-5 p-5 z-depth-1 unique-color-dark">
                <section class="text-center white-text">
                    <h2 class="font-weight-bold mb-4 pb-2 text-uppercase">Эффекты</h2>
                    <p class="lead mx-auto mb-5">В зависимости от сорта чая, эффект может отличаться, но почти все
                        виды сходятся в нескольких вещах</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 features">
                            <h5 class="font-weight-bold my-4 text-uppercase">Тонизирует</h5>
                            <p class="mb-md-0 mb-5">Пуэр очень хорошо употреблять перед спортивными тренировками,
                                перед экзаменами, водителям во время дальней дороги.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 features">
                            <h5 class="font-weight-bold my-4 text-uppercase">Улучшает пищеварение</h5>
                            <p class="mb-md-0 mb-5"> При регулярном употреблении улучшает пищеварение и обмен
                                веществ в организме
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 features">
                            <h5 class="font-weight-bold my-4 text-uppercase">Успокаивает</h5>
                            <p class="mb-0"> Помогает сосредоточиться, справиться со стрессом, взять себя в руки
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
```

Элементы выглядят так: Подскажите пожалуйста как выровнять их по вертикали, то есть чтобы все три элемента были на одной линии

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста стили которые сейчас у вас есть, а то не очень понятно - вам нужно как на картинке или у вас сейчас так как на картинке а нужно иначе

Comment: Сейчас, очевидно, выравнивание (на картинке) по-вертикали у блоков выставлено по центру. Похоже надо, по верхнему краю. Но дальше - фиг знает. Как оформлены стили. через флексы, гриды и проч. Нужен пример стилей.

Comment: здесь MDBoostrap, никаких стилей дополнительных не использовал

Answer (score 0):

Оберните эти 3 блока в еще один блок и задай ему будстраповський класс d-flex